# Setter and Getter problems

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

Why is the if statment not executing in the setter for age()? It should return **"Age must be a number";**

The get statment works but not the set statment.

```
class Player {
    constructor(name, age, position) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
        this._position = position;
    }
set age(value){ 
    if(value.isNaN()) {
        return "Age must be a number";
    } else {
        return this._age;
    }
}
get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
get age() {
    if(typeof this._age === "number") {
        return this._age;
    }else{
        return "Cant fetch players age"
    }
}
get position() {
    return this._position;
}
};
const test = new Player("Peter", "38", "Forward")
console.log(test.age)
```

Comment: You're not calling the setter anywhere, you carefully *bypass* it in the constructor. Also note setters don't return things.

Comment: Additionally, `isNaN` tries to convert the argument to number before checking, "38" converts to number, and `isNaN` returns `false`.

Comment: hmm okey i saw my error with the "return this._age" and i changed isNaN() to a typeof statment.. but it still doesnt work... i dont get what you mean by bypass.

Comment: You don’t set the value to this.age or vise-versa in your setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your constructor should call the setter instead of instance variable:

```
class Player {
    constructor(name, age, position) {
        this._name = name;
        this.age = age;  //call setter
        this._position = position;
    }
    ...
```